# Copy existing table with NULLABLE column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem, I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Committee 
(
    CommitteeID INT NOT NULL, 
    CommitteeName varchar(250),
    CommitteeMemberID INT
)
```

Where in the `CommitteeName` column and `CommitteeMemberID` is not nullable.

Now I want to create a temporary table with the same column as the `Committee` table but with all NULLABLE columns.

I tried using this

```
select top 0 c.* 
into #oldValues 
from Committee as c
```

but this exactly copies the column of `Committee` table.

How to make it nullable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i want to copy the column but with nullable

Comment: i already get the solution. thanks